# C# simple subtraction from two different database

Tags: c#, postgresql, sqlite, math

I have 2 different databases - SQLite and PostgreSQL and i trying to make tiny math on table from this databases.
Both tables contains columns nr_serii and ilosc, SQLite:

[image: SQLite]

And Postgres:

[image]

I established a connection to both databases and populate dataset. Maybe i should use different place to store the data?

I need to substraction column ilosc: (sqlite-postgres), but not know how to do that.
For example, for each nr_serii make substraction column ilosc:

nr_serii:222222

ilosc:15-7=8

Finally i want to show output data to datagridview.
When i use messagebox i can see the data in dataset. Here is my part of code:

```
            string cs = @"URI = file:" + Sdatabase;
            string csP = conParam;
            string sqlP = "select nr_serii, ilosc from stany";
            string sql = "select nr_serii, ilosc from przychod";
            
            using var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            using var conP = new NpgsqlConnection(csP);
            conP.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmdP = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlP, conP);
            NpgsqlDataAdapter DA = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmdP);
            DataSet dsP = new DataSet();
            DA.Fill(dsP);
            //----------test-----------
            foreach (DataRow row in dsP.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                var nr_serii = row["nr_serii"];
                var ilosc = row["ilosc"];
                MessageBox.Show(nr_serii +","+ ilosc);
            }
            
            //--------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can browse data table from first datasource *ds* and search for a matching row by value of *nr_serii* column for each row in the datatable in second datasource *dsP*, and if found, add a new row with the calculation result to the new third result table.

Then you don't forget to solve the problem of what to do with records that are only in the first *ds* or only in the second *dsP* datasource, depending on the value of the *nr_serii* column.

Program code example:

```
//prepare result third DataTable
DataTable resultDt = new DataTable();
resultDt.Columns.Add("nr_serii");
resultDt.Columns.Add("ilosc");
//add content to result DataTable
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var nr_serii = row["nr_serii"];
    var ilosc = row["ilosc"];
    DataRow drP = null;
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dsP.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (nr_serii.ToString() == (string)dataRow["nr_serii"])
        {
            drP = dataRow;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (drP != null)
    {
        var dr = resultDt.NewRow();
        dr["nr_serii"] = nr_serii;
        dr["ilosc"] = (int)ilosc - (int)drP["ilosc"];
        resultDt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```